# New VS C++ update is making boost forward declared code un-compilable ! What can you do?

Tags: c++, boost, compiler-errors, visual-c++

These are the new errors I get when I try to use a project that I am building that uses Boost as statically linked libraries. But the very includes alone cry in compilation. Please advice.

Boost Version : 1.68

Visual Studio version (Community) : 15.8.0 , Last updated Aug 14, 2018.

```
   Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
    Error   C4643   Forward declaring 'allocator' in namespace std is not permitted by the C++ Standard.boost-root\boost\detail\container_fwd.hpp   119 
    Error   C4643   Forward declaring 'allocator' in namespace std is not permitted by the C++ Standard.boost-root\boost\detail\container_fwd.hpp   119 
    Error   C4643   Forward declaring 'allocator' in namespace std is not permitted by the C++ Standard.boost-root\boost\detail\container_fwd.hpp   119 
    Error   C4643   Forward declaring 'allocator' in namespace std is not permitted by the C++ Standard.boost-root\boost\container\detail\std_fwd.hpp   30  
    Error   C4643   Forward declaring 'allocator' in namespace std is not permitted by the C++ Standard.boost-root\boost\detail\container_fwd.hpp   119 
    Error   C4643   Forward declaring 'allocator' in namespace std is not permitted by the C++ Standard.boost-root\boost\container\detail\std_fwd.hpp   30  
    Error   C4643   Forward declaring 'allocator_arg_t' in namespace std is not permitted by the C++ Standard.boost-root\boost\container\detail\std_fwd.hpp 49  
    Error   C4643   Forward declaring 'allocator_arg_t' in namespace std is not permitted by the C++ Standard.boost-root\boost\container\detail\std_fwd.hpp 49  
    Error   C4643   Forward declaring 'basic_istream' in namespace std is not permitted by the C++ Standard.boost-root\boost\interprocess\detail\std_fwd.hpp    47  
    Error   C4643   Forward declaring 'basic_istream' in namespace std is not permitted by the C++ Standard.boost-root\boost\interprocess\detail\std_fwd.hpp    47  
    Error   C4643   Forward declaring 'basic_ostream' in namespace std is not permitted by the C++ Standard.boost-root\boost\interprocess\detail\std_fwd.hpp    44  
    Error   C4643   Forward declaring 'basic_ostream' in namespace std is not permitted by the C++ Standard.boost-root\boost\interprocess\detail\std_fwd.hpp    44  
    Error   C4643   Forward declaring 'basic_string' in namespace std is not permitted by the C++ Standard.boost-root\boost\detail\container_fwd.hpp    120 
    Error   C4643   Forward declaring 'basic_string' in namespace std is not permitted by the C++ Standard.boost-root\boost\detail\container_fwd.hpp    120 
    Error   C4643   Forward declaring 'basic_string' in namespace std is not permitted by the C++ Standard.boost-root\boost\detail\container_fwd.hpp    120 
    Error   C4643   Forward declaring 'basic_string' in namespace std is not permitted by the C++ Standard.boost-root\boost\detail\container_fwd.hpp    120 
    Error   C4643   Forward declaring 'bidirectional_iterator_tag' in namespace std is not permitted by the C++ Standard.boost-root\boost\move\detail\iterator_traits.hpp   33  
    Error   C4643   Forward declaring 'bidirectional_iterator_tag' in namespace std is not permitted by the C++ Standard.boost-root\boost\move\detail\iterator_traits.hpp   33  
    Error   C4643   Forward declaring 'bidirectional_iterator_tag' in namespace std is not permitted by the C++ Standard.boost-root\boost\container\detail\std_fwd.hpp  43  
    Error   C4643   Forward declaring 'bidirectional_iterator_tag' in namespace std is not permitted by the C++ Standard.boost-root\boost\interprocess\detail\std_fwd.hpp   30  
    Error   C4643   Forward declaring 'bidirectional_iterator_tag' in namespace std is not permitted by the C++ Standard.boost-root\boost\move\detail\iterator_traits.hpp   33  
    Error   C4643   Forward declaring 'bidirectional_iterator_tag' in namespace std is not permitted by the C++ Standard.boost-root\boost\move\detail\iterator_traits.hpp   33  
    Error   C4643   Forward declaring 'bidirectional_iterator_tag' in namespace std is not permitted by the C++ Standard.boost-root\boost\container\detail\std_fwd.hpp  43  
    Error   C4643   Forward declaring 'bidirectional_iterator_tag' in namespace std is not permitted by the C++ Standard.boost-root\boost\interprocess\detail\std_fwd.hpp   30  
    Error   C4643   Forward declaring 'bitset' in namespace std is not permitted by the C++ Standard.boost-root\boost\detail\container_fwd.hpp  143 
    Error   C4643   Forward declaring 'bitset' in namespace std is not permitted by the C++ Standard.boost-root\boost\detail\container_fwd.hpp  143 
    Error   C4643   Forward declaring 'bitset' in namespace std is not permitted by the C++ Standard.boost-root\boost\detail\container_fwd.hpp  143 
    Error   C4643   Forward declaring 'bitset' in namespace std is not permitted by the C++ Standard.boost-root\boost\detail\container_fwd.hpp  143 
    Error   C4643   Forward declaring 'char_traits' in namespace std is not permitted by the C++ Standard.boost-root\boost\detail\container_fwd.hpp 122 
    Error   C4643   Forward declaring 'char_traits' in namespace std is not permitted by the C++ Standard.boost-root\boost\detail\container_fwd.hpp 122 
    Error   C4643   Forward declaring 'char_traits' in namespace std is not permitted by the C++ Standard.boost-root\boost\detail\container_fwd.hpp 122 
    Error   C4643   Forward declaring 'char_traits' in namespace std is not permitted by the C++ Standard.boost-root\boost\container\detail\std_fwd.hpp 39  
    Error   C4643   Forward declaring 'char_traits' in namespace std is not permitted by the C++ Standard.boost-root\boost\interprocess\detail\std_fwd.hpp  34  
    Error   C4643   Forward declaring 'char_traits' in namespace std is not permitted by the C++ Standard.boost-root\boost\detail\container_fwd.hpp 122 
    Error   C4643   Forward declaring 'char_traits' in namespace std is not permitted by the C++ Standard.boost-root\boost\container\detail\std_fwd.hpp 39  
    Error   C4643   Forward declaring 'char_traits' in namespace std is not permitted by the C++ Standard.boost-root\boost\interprocess\detail\std_fwd.hpp  34  
    Error   C4643   Forward declaring 'complex' in namespace std is not permitted by the C++ Standard.boost-root\boost\detail\container_fwd.hpp 127 
    Error   C4643   Forward declaring 'complex' in namespace std is not permitted by the C++ Standard.boost-root\boost\detail\container_fwd.hpp 127 
    Error   C4643   Forward declaring 'complex' in namespace std is not permitted by the C++ Standard.boost-root\boost\detail\container_fwd.hpp 127 
    Error   C4643   Forward declaring 'complex' in namespace std is not permitted by the C++ Standard.boost-root\boost\detail\container_fwd.hpp 127 
    Error   C4643   Forward declaring 'deque' in namespace std is not permitted by the C++ Standard.boost-root\boost\detail\container_fwd.hpp   131 
    Error   C4643   Forward declaring 'deque' in namespace std is not permitted by the C++ Standard.boost-root\boost\detail\container_fwd.hpp   131 
    Error   C4643   Forward declaring 'deque' in namespace std is not permitted by the C++ Standard.boost-root\boost\detail\container_fwd.hpp   131 
    Error   C4643   Forward declaring 'deque' in namespace std is not permitted by the C++ Standard.boost-root\boost\detail\container_fwd.hpp   131 
    Error   C4643   Forward declaring 'forward_iterator_tag' in namespace std is not permitted by the C++ Standard.boost-root\boost\move\detail\iterator_traits.hpp 32  
    Error   C4643   Forward declaring 'forward_iterator_tag' in namespace std is not permitted by the C++ Standard.boost-root\boost\move\detail\iterator_traits.hpp 32
```

Comment: I get about 113 errors, couldn't paste them all, but they are all the same. Why does Microsoft accepts some syntax enforcing in its update when it has not even been tested on such a standard library like boost I just don't understand !

Comment: TIP: It's better / cleaner to copy the errors from the Output Tab of Visual Studio.

Comment: Also thanks for the info. I will hold off updating VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shame indeed... For now check out this:

> **Bug fixes and behavior changes in Visual Studio 2017 version 15.8**
>
> ...
>
> **forward declarations and definitions in namespace std**
>
> The C++ standard doesn't allow a user to add forward declarations or definitions into namespace std. Adding declarations or definitions to namespace std or to a namespace within namespace std now results in undefined behavior.
>
> At some time in the future, Microsoft will move the location where
> some STL types are defined. When this happens, it will break existing
> code that adds forward declarations to namespace std. A new warning,
> C4643, helps identify such source issues. The warning is enabled
> in **/default** mode and is off by default. It will impact programs that
> are compiled with **/Wall** or **/WX**

From [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/cpp-docs/blob/master/docs/cpp-conformance-improvements-2017.md).

To avoid this error until further changes to conform are made inside the relevant headers, add this before including them:

```
#pragma warning( disable : 4643 )
```

This will solve it for now even for code being built from within Unreal Engine 4.

For regular MSVC compiling, either manual or from within VS, make sure you're not compiling with `/WX` as **it will make the warnings into errors.**

Also, not that I recommend this as a long term solution, but if you just want to see that you can get it back to build successfully, you can disable the [`/permissive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/permissive-standards-conformance) compiler flag that was introduced in 15.3 to aid enforcing standard conformance.

Comment: "A new warning C4643" ? I often ignore warnings that are flagged on Boost source code. They spit out C4643 errors !

Comment: So the cause of this is `using namespace std;`??

Comment: @Syed Alam Abbas I've added some tips to help get you back to compiling error free. Let me know where it stands.

Comment: @SkepticalEmpiricist I wish things were this easy to set some flags and I could see if I can build it. But I am using Unreal Engine 4 and in it I have a c++ project which in turn has the boost libraries as plugin. So any such compiler level flag change would mean I have to rebuild the whole engine to see if this works(build tool level chain automatically triggers whole rebuild). I will try that thing overnight or so. But thank you so much for providing right pointers in the direction where its likely to succeed.

Comment: @SkepticalEmpiricist I tried the configurable option for unreal engine to use the /permissive flag, it does not compile. I get another set of issue when using this setting since other project DX12 related that were compiling no longer works.  See here : https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Programming/UnrealBuildSystem/Configuration                                                            WindowsPlatform
bStrictConformanceMode
Enables strict standard conformance mode (/permissive-) in VS2017+.

Comment: @SyedAlamAbbas You've turned this flag ON?

Comment: I have tried on and off both by now without any success :) I have now even asked this on the Microsoft forum : https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/312706/new-vs-c-update-is-making-boost-forward-declared-c.html

Comment: @SyedAlamAbbas OK obviously I meant trying with such conformance flags OFF, not on, to get error-free compilation. But just a quick recap so we could get to solving this ASAP -- The error ridden compilation output from above (in the question), was given to you when trying to compile from within Unreal Engine 4?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178144/discussion-between-syed-alam-abbas-and-skepticalempiricist).

Comment: Thank you SkepticalEmp for all the help, a very fine fix that was badly needed, when it comes to persistence you Sir are a honey badger !